# Comments Inside Text Block in Java 17 - Is that possible?

Tags: java

A simple question. Is it possible to have comments in Text Blocks in Java 17?

Since Java 15 Text Blocks are an option:

```
"""
   Hello Hello                    //how to create a comment here? - this was wanted by customer XXX
This dog has a big nose        // This line came with version 1.0.2
This cat needs to eat
"""
```

Is it possible to have comments inside a text block? I would like to tag some lines that came with new customers etc. Is this possible, will this be possible?

Comment: If you need to comment individual lines of a single text block based on different customers or versions, maybe you shouldn't be using a single text block to begin with. Sounds like questionable design.

Comment: It was more or less theoretical question :) I am not using it at the moment... I might come in handy at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [JEP 378](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378), it is **not** possible to add a comment in a text block.

However, you can use a few tricks:

For example, you can replace everything inside of `/*... */`:

```java
"""
abc /* this is a comment*/
def //another comment
""".replace("/\\*.*\*/","").replace("//.*$","");
```

Another possibility would be to use multiple text blocks:

```java
"""
... 
"""
+ //comment
"""
... 
"""
```

However, as [Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca) mentioned in the comments, these are just workarounds. It is likely better to include a comment before the text block explaining what it does in general instead of writing comments in the text blocks.

Comment: Love that `replace` hack, but I swear that if I see that in actual code I'll personally smack on the head whoever `git blame` says did that.

Comment: I am just giving an answer, what people do with it is their problem.

Comment: Mine was more of a humorous take than anything, but since you brought it up I think it's important to remember that people will read your answer and consider you an expert on the subject (otherwise you wouldn't be responding) and think that's the correct way to do it. So while yes, it's their problem, you should also consider that you're teaching less experienced developers. Again, I don't feel so strongly about this, otherwise I would have downvoted your answer, but I think it's worth thinking about :-)

Comment: The replace one is an awesome hack :) However none of the IDE would recognize it  probably so I guess it is not really what I was looking for. 

However as everyone already mentioned I guess it is not possible in Java at the moment - I was wondering if that would be possible with like the use of some special escape characters or sth :) 

The + thing is also a good trick :)

Answer (score 15):

The Java Language Specification [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7) that:

> The lexical grammar implies that comments do not occur within character literals, string literals, or **text blocks**

(emphasis mine)

So nope, you can't do that.

Comment: I would like to mark this as an answer as well - but the replace answer is an interesting hack that i prefer - otherwise would love to mark both :)

I do understand the no comments in String literals etc - I think the text block should allow them - with some escape strategy .. The workarounds - especially the one with splitting the block is usable.. but not the nicest - I hope that Java Lang. Spec. will change to include these comments as well :)

Comment: @Jack I wouldn't count on the spec changing towards that direction as it would be a backward compatibility breaker (imagine strings actually containing that escape sequence *before* they decided it was an escape sequence).

Comment: They would be simply printed out? :)

Comment: @Jack yes, and that would be a problem, don't you think? :)

Comment: I guess it should depend - escape sequences are also in the Text Block now - \t works and stuff... in any case I am more or less just starting out - so I will trust your judgement :) For me what I will do: 
 - break the Block (+)
 - add a normal "String" // with the comment
 - and continue the block after it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specially for Java but I would think that no it isn't possible to do this as some people would want to have text with `//` in the strings without escaping.

Comment: At the moment I guess it really isn't - however with some new escape strategy i think it should be possible? :)